# How to Get value within button and append to div table

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value in the button (50 or 49) to append to my div table and the header name as well (Name/Nr.) ?

I need the value in the Input button (50 or 49) to appear in the div table when i click on the "use-address" button and remove it when I Re-click the "use-address" to remove selection:

```js
$(".use-address").click(function() {
  var $item = $(this).closest("tr") // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    .find(".nr") // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
    .text(); // Retrieves the text within <td>

  $("#resultas").append($item); // Outputs the answer
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart" Id="resultas">
  <div id="resultas"></div>
</div>
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
      <th>Name/Nr.</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Town</th>
      <th>Postcode</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="50"></td>
      <td>Some Street 1</td>
      <td>Leeds</td>
      <td>L0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="use-address" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="49"></td>
      <td>Some Street 2</td>
      <td>Lancaster</td>
      <td>L0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="use-address" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `val()`, not `text()`, to retrieve the value from the related button. In addition you should use `text()` to set the content of `#resultas` so that only the last vaule which was clicked is dislpayed.

```js
$(".use-address").click(function() {
  var item = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").val();
  $("#resultas").text((i, t) => t === item ? '' : item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart" Id="resultas">
  <div id="resultas"></div>
</div>
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
      <th>Name/Nr.</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Town</th>
      <th>Postcode</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="50"></td>
      <td>Some Street 1</td>
      <td>Leeds</td>
      <td>L0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="use-address" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" class="nr" value="49"></td>
      <td>Some Street 2</td>
      <td>Lancaster</td>
      <td>L0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="use-address" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Lets Say Now I Need It to remove the 50 when I re-click the first button but add 49 when i click the 2nd button how do i edit my code to do that?

Comment: To do what you need you can use a condition to check if the current value matches what is being set, and if so clear it. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: Yes but now its only changing text and not adding multiple results on click, I need it to add selections to a cart (div) and when I re-click on the selected buttons it must remove as in the selection was un-selected

Comment: In that case change `text()` to `append()`, however it makes little sense as you'll end up with a string like `50505050`. It would be better to build an array of values in that case. I'd suggest starting a new question about this if you have problems implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there

replace

```
.text(); with .val()
```

And replace below if you dont want multiple results on click

```
$("#resultas").append($item); with $("#resultas").text(item);
```